# how to split string data using criterion in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i wondering about something expression of string list in dataframe.
how to split string value using python?
I'm using replace method. 
But, i can't find a way to delete only the node number.

dataframe

```
index    article_id
0      ['@abc_172', '@abc_249', '@abc-32', '@def-1']
1      ['@az3_2', '@bwc_4', '@xc-34', '@xc-1']   
2      ['@ac_12']
3      ['#ea457870a2d32453609f52e50f84abdc_15', '@bb_3']
4       ...
...     ...
```

I want to get like this

```
index       article_id                      article_id_unique_count
0      ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'def']                   2
1      ['az3', 'bwc', 'xc', 'xc']                     3
2      ['ac']                                         1
3      ['#ea457870a2d32453609f52e50f84abdc', 'bb']    2

 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `re.findall`

```
df['article_id'] =  df.article_id.apply(lambda x: re.findall('([#a-z0-9]+)',x)).apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i.isdigit() == False])

df['article_id_unique_count'] = df['article_id'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
```

**Output**

```
                                article_id  article_id_unique_count
0                     [abc, abc, abc, def]                        2
1                       [az3, bwc, xc, xc]                        3
2                                     [ac]                        1
3  [#ea457870a2d32453609f52e50f84abdc, bb]                        2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm really appreciate your help. And i want know about like this value "#ea457870a2d32453609f52e50f84abdc_15". This is article_id that diffrent from  others id value. 
How can i
 combine this to modify it?

Comment: whats the expected output..abdc ?

Comment: Ok, i'll try your recommend method!

Comment: the output doesn't match `ea457870a2d32453609f52e50f84abdc` # is missing

Comment: Just saying. It isn't worth total 5 `apply` for this kind of question. You should try to optimize to reduce less `apply`

Comment: thanks for the feedback..looking into it..if you have any suggestion, edits are welcome..@AndyL.

Comment: I prefer solution without `apply` at all :)

Answer (score 0):

apply regex within apply and set to count unique elements in the list

```
import re
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"id":[0,1,2],
                        "article_id":[["abc_172", "@abc_249", "@abc-32", "@def-1"],
                                      ["@az3_2", "@bwc_4", "@xc-34", "@xc-1"],
                                      ["@#ea457870a2d32453609f52e50f84abdc_15"]]})

df['article_id'] = df['article_id'].apply(lambda x : re.sub('[!@$]','', i).split("-")[0].split("_")[0] for i in x])
df['article_id_unique_count'] = df['article_id'].apply(lambda x : len(set(x)))
```

```
   id                           article_id  article_id_unique_count
0   0                 [abc, abc, abc, def]                        2
1   1                   [az3, bwc, xc, xc]                        3
2   2  [#ea457870a2d32453609f52e50f84abdc]                        1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm really appreciate your help. 
As mentioned above, i want know about like this value "#ea457870a2d32453609f52e50f84abdc_15". This is article_id that diffrent from others id value. How can i combine this to modify it?

Comment: `re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+','', i)` this regex actaully fetch only alphabets from the string,you need to define what kind of characters you want to fetch from string

Comment: `#ea457870a2d32453609f52e50f84abdc_15` against this article_id what should be the right articleId ? according to my regex it would only extract alphabets

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the delimiters are either `-` or `_`:

```
df['article_id'].map(lambda x:[re.findall('@*(.+?)[-_]', s)[0] for s in x], 1)
```

Output:

```
0                       [abc, abc, abc, def]
1                         [az3, bwc, xc, xc]
2                                       [ac]
3    [#ea457870a2d32453609f52e50f84abdc, bb]
```

You can then use `apply(lambda x:len(set(x)))`.

Notice that the first element of row 1, `az3` is also correctly extracted.

Comment: Thank you Chris, i try your recommend method but it's run error. like this "IndexError: list index out of range". What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions using `apply`. I always try to find a solution without using `apply`. I come up with this one. Simple construct dataframe from the list, `stack` to series and work with `str.extract` and `agg`

```
(pd.DataFrame(df.article_id.tolist(), index=df.index).stack().str.extract(r'@?(.*)[_-]')
            .groupby(level=0)[0].agg([list, 'nunique'])
            .rename(columns={'list': 'article_id', 'nunique': 'article_id_unique_count'}))

Out[15]:
                                article_id  article_id_unique_count
0                     [abc, abc, abc, def]                        2
1                       [az3, bwc, xc, xc]                        3
2                                     [ac]                        1
3  [#ea457870a2d32453609f52e50f84abdc, bb]                        2
```